# find out available space (width) when there is a floated element

Tags: jquery, css-float

I've got a floated element (`float:left`) width approximately `500px` of space on the right Is there a way, to find out how much space is available via jQuery? I want to do this dynamically and would love a jQuery way.

So I want to insert an element and let it be as big as there is space available.

Comment: any reason you cant use width: 100% on a second left-floated element?

Comment: the second element is a ckeditor. Its actually just breaking the layout, because it uses the full width and doesn't care about the floated element...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your content inserted in a fixed-width container? If so, just calculate the exact width of your left-floated element and subtract it from the width of the container.

If it's not a fixed-width container, calculate that width first.

Example:

```
<div>
    <span style="float:left;">a</span>
</div>
```

The resulting width, for your third element:

```
var availWidth = $('div').width() - $('span').width(); //Use proper selectors here
```

Comment: i already reached there... :-) But what, if I don't know, if there is a floated element? Is there a way to find this out?